# возможно ли вытащить класс из переменной?php Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
foreach ($prefixLinks as $key => $prefixLink){
             
            echo $model = $key . '<br>';
           
}
//вывод
Page
Post



$model::all();// //Class 'Page' not found ,  а нужно чтобы можно было  чтобы выполнить запрос
```

Comment: В чём смысл? ЧТо пытаетесь сделать? `App\$model::all();`

Comment: $model = 'App\\Models\\'. $key; решил так

Comment: Это я так понимаю связано с вопросом поиска? Если так то вам нужен union

Comment: А как создается массив `$prefixLinks`? Не было бы проще держать ключем сам класс там? Это можно всегда сделать, например вот так: `\App\Models\Page::class`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($prefixLinks as $key => $prefixLink){
    $model = 'App\\Models\\'. $key;
}
```